# how to implement Keycloak custom user federation provider with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have already implemented a custom user federation provider that automatically integrates my user data from my MySQL database into Keycloak.
Now I would like to switch to MongoDB and adapt my custom user federation for my MongoDB accordingly.
My first question is, is it possible/supported to create a custom user federation provider with MongoDB?
If so, can you point me to helpful links and sources that can help me?
Thank you so much! ^^

Comment: You can write your own User Storage  SPI (as you did with MySQL). Check please https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_user-storage-spi   Example of mysql https://github.com/kyrcha/keycloak-mysql-user-federation